# Is the topological entropy of a continuous map $T\colon X\to X$ zero if $X$ is a finite topological space?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, dynamical-systems, entropy

Let $X$ be a finite topological space and $T\colon X\to X$ continuous. As the title already suggests, I am wondering if the topological entropy of $T$, denoted by $h(X,T)$, then is $0$.

As far as I see, this is indeed the case. Before giving my reason, let's give me the definition of topological entropy given by Adler, Konheim and McAndrew (see Peter Walters' *An Introduction to Ergodic Theory*).

> > **Definition 1** If $\alpha$ is an open cover of X let $N(\alpha)$ denote the number of sets in a finite subcover of $\alpha$ with smallest cardinality. We define the entropy of $\alpha$ by $H(\alpha)=\log N(\alpha)$.
> >
> > **Definition 2** If $\alpha$ is an open cover of $X$ and $T\colon X\to X$ is a continuous map then the entropy of $T$ relative to $\alpha$ is given by $h(T,\alpha)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}H\left(\bigvee_{i=0}^{n-1}T^{-i}\alpha\right)$, where $\bigvee_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i$ is the join of any finite collection of open covers of $X$.
> >
> > **Definition 3** If $T\colon X\to X$ is continuous, the topological entropy of $T$ is given by $h(T)=\sup_{\alpha}h(T,\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ ranges over all open covers of $X$.

Now, let $\alpha$ be any open cover of $X$. Since $X$ is finite,  $N\left(\bigvee_{i=0}^{n-1}T^{-i}\alpha\right)\le\text{card}(X)<\infty$. Hence
$$
0\le h(T,\alpha)\le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log\text{card}(X)=0,
$$
implying that $h(T,\alpha)=0$, implying that $h(T)=\sup_{\alpha}h(T,\alpha)=0$.

Please let me know if I am right. Thank you.

Comment: Finite spaces are always compact.

Comment: Hi M. Meyer: I don´t know this topic , however I think if this were true for all finite X then always  it would be said in the basic books.Welcome.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are correct, I improved it.

Comment: I don't see any problem in your argument.